# Twitter Streams API with Heroku

Tags: heroku, sinatra, hashtag, twitter-streaming-api

Hi I'm really becoming mad with this problem. I need to continuously post to another server some tweets, in realtime. They are filtered by a hashtag.

I'm using this solution: http://joslynesser.com/blog/archives/2010/09/12/consuming-the-twitter-streaming-api-with-heroku-and-mongodb/#comment-form

If I change it to use filter.json it works (alias retrieves tweets) only with words that have a lot of traffic on Heroku, while it works with my hashtag from my local machine. I tried with different accounts.

Anyone can please shed light?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I sorted it out, with the TweetStream gem. See the code here: https://github.com/aledalgrande/mongo-twitter-streaming/blob/master/app.rb

Fully working on Heroku!!!